# Pattern not surrounded by numbers or alphanumerics

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to find some words not surrounded by any numerics or alphanumerics or surrounded by nothing.
So if I'm looking for Foo123 I would like this result

```
="Foo123"; =>TRUE
barFoo123; =>FALSE
Foo123 =>TRUE
BarBar123Foo123Bar; =>FALSE
;Foo123 =>TRUE
```

I just built this expression:

```
(^[^0-9a-zA-Z]?)WORDTOFIND([^0-9a-zA-Z]?$)
```

I was pretty sure I'm in the right way but when I'm using it like this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(line, string.Format(@"(^[^0-9a-zA-Z]?){0}([^0-9a-zA-Z]?$)",snCode)) )
{   
}
```

It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're essentially looking for

```
 (?<![a-zA-Z0-9])Foo123(?![a-zA-Z0-9])
```

This uses a lookahead and lookbehind to make sure that there isn't an alphanumeric character either before or after `Foo123`. This assumes ASCII, though.

Comment: Right, the important difference is that you say `Foo123` must not be preceded by an alphanumeric character, instead of saying it must be preceded by an optional non-alphanumeric character at the start of the string. You clearly express the intent, and that typically gets good results.

Comment: This is not working but your previous do : (?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])Foo123(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9]) Can someone tell me what is <= ?

Comment: No, it works.  @Joey just forgot to remove one of the carets: `(?![^a-zA-Z0-9])` should be `(?![a-zA-Z0-9])`.

Answer (score 0):

The following matches the strings you do NOT want so do `!Regex.IsMatch()`

```
(^([0-9a-zA-Z])+{0}.*)|(.*{0}([0-9a-zA-Z])+)
```

Comment: Point #1 is irrelevant: if `[a-zA-Z0-9]` is true, then by definition `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` is true, too.  Point #2 is solved by using negative lookarounds instead of negated character classes, as @Joey's answer demonstrates.

Comment: @AlanMoore 1) Understood 2) Decided to give my answer because Joey's answer fails on "barFoo123;". It's now marked as accepted though. Updated my answer.